# CPTPlotSymbol larger touch area

Tags: ios, core-plot

How can I make the plot symbol touch area bigger. 10x10 is what I need to be filled with color, but it is really hard to touch on the screen with 'fat' fingers. So I need the area around it to activate the symbol, but not to be filled with color.

```
CPTMutableLineStyle *symbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    symbolLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:42./255. green:150./255. blue:232./255. alpha:1.];
CPTPlotSymbol *plotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
plotSymbol.fill               = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:42./255. green:150./255. blue:232./255. alpha:1.]];
plotSymbol.lineStyle          = symbolLineStyle;
plotSymbol.size               = CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0);
dataSourceLinePlot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method that you make the plot and the graph there should be a line that goes like this.

```
_yourGraph.plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection = 20.0f;
```

I always use 20.0f because of 'fat' fingers too.  I have a method that I called configurePlots, I get a reference to the graph and plot space.  Then I call the plotSymbol...  Hope this helps, ask questions if you have any.

Comment: thanks
CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
dataSourceLinePlot.plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection = 30.;

Comment: @Zsolt, glad to help!  Core plot is great!